# Centering an element horizontally, staying in the bounds of parent div, at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my text to be centered horizontally on the main part of the page, while behaving like the sidebar doesn't exist. I additionally also want it to be at the very bottom of the page.

```css
#chat-form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<section id="bottom-notice" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; background-color: red;">
            <form id="chat-form">
                <p style="color: #9a9a9e; font-size: 12px;">This text is the bane of my existence</p>
            </form>
        </section>
```

My idea was to have a parent div that would put it at the bottom with an absolute position, and to then

Have the child be centered horizontally like this, the justify-content centering it while respecting other divs.
However it behaves very weirdly and is too far on the right.
I can get the text to be centered respecting the sidebar and to be at the bottom, but never both at the same time.
Ive tried a bunch of stuff, but none of them brought me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem. From the following code, your sidebar will be fixed on the left side and your text will remain on the bottom of the page without considering the position of the sidebar. For the demonstration purpose, I have written down HTML and CSS separately.

```css
.container{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color: #000000;
  color:#ffffff;
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
}
.text{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">My Sidebar</div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>This text is the bane of my existence</p>
  </div>
</div>
```